# Difference between SOP and PSOP

Tags: pcb-design, h-bridge, altium

I am trying to create a custom PSOP footprint in Altium designer using the IPC compliant footprint wizard. The datasheet of the ic says that it is a PSOP (plastic small outline package). In the wizard there is an option for a SOP/TSOP package with Gullwing leads, but not for PSOP. The included packages are SOP, TSOP and TSSOP.

Can I select this option to create my footprint for the PSOP package. The ic I am using is an NCV7729 8A H-bridge driver from ON semiconductor.

Comment: You could try it out and then compare the generated results with the footprint information in the datasheet.

Comment: I don't think it matters. As the P stands for Plastic, it should not change anything as long as the footprint is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manufacturer variation naming for their specific type of Sop sized device. Not all sop are the same  anyway, with number of pins, width, height, pin types, etc.

Always compare the datasheet information to your cad software package  footprint.

Comment: All those parameters are part of the wizard, after the package type/category has been selected.